# React Router (v6) useNavigate TypeScript error: "TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'To'"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I want to use navigate() to go back in history, but TypeScript shows me an error: ***TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'To'***.

How can I fix this issue?

```
const navigate = useNavigate()

useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  dispatch(fetchUser(userId!))
    .unwrap()
    .then(({ data }: { data: User }) => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setUser(data);
    })
    .catch(() => navigate(-1, { replace: true }));
}, []);
```

Comment: Leave only `navigate(-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate) type declaration:

> ```
> declare function useNavigate(): NavigateFunction;
>
> interface NavigateFunction {
>   (
>     to: To,
>     options?: { replace?: boolean; state?: any }
>   ): void;
>   (delta: number): void;
> }
> ```

The interface expects ***either*** `To` and `options` arguments ***or*** a single `delta` argument.

By passing two args the types on the first arg no longer match and `-1` isn't assignable to the `To` prop.

Delta navigations only navigate forward/backward through the history stack, so it doesn't make sense to tray and make it a redirect. Remove the second arg.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  dispatch(fetchUser(userId!))
    .unwrap()
    .then(({ data }: { data: User }) => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setUser(data);
    })
    .catch(() => navigate(-1)); // <-- only delta value
}, []);
```